# file:/// URL permission for Chromium

Tags: chromium

My experimental Chromium extension would like run some content scripts on local HTML pages. I've in my manifest.json file

```
"permission": [
 ...
 "file:///*/*"
]
```

and I've checked the "Allow access to file URL's" in the extension management page. However, I'm not seeing the effect. I expected it to add an item to the context menu, but it doesn't in the local page, while it works on web pages. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set up the "matches" filter correctly in the "content_scripts" section of you manifest.